# Difference in weeks between first occurance and current occurance

Tags: pandas, date, datetime

I have a large dataset including items and dates. The simplified version looks as follows:

| Item | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2018-10-01 |
| 2 | 2018-04-03 |
| 1 | 2018-10-16 |
| 2 | 2018-04-15 |
| 1 | 2018-10-20 |
| 2 | 2018-04-30 |

I want to add the column df['ItemAge'], displaying the number of weeks between the date of the occurrence of the item and the date of the first date of occurrence of the item. Here, the number of weeks is rounded to whole integers. The value of this variable is 0 on the date that the item first occurred. Hence I want to obtain:

| Item | Date | ItemAge |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2018-10-01 | 0 |
| 2 | 2018-04-03 | 0 |
| 1 | 2018-10-16 | 2 |
| 2 | 2018-04-15 | 2 |
| 1 | 2018-10-20 | 3 |
| 2 | 2018-04-30 | 4 |

I am thinking about creating the variable StartDate for each item as the date of the first occurrence of each item. Subsequently looping over the items and taking the difference in days between the new occurrence of the item and its StartDate. Then dividing this number of days by 7 and rounding to whole integers.

However, I don't know how to write this code in python. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: *"I am thinking about […]"*, the whole process is there, there is no indication that this is homework

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to datetime, `groupby` Item and [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) to take the first date per group. Then get the number of days by dividing the resulting TimeDelta by 7:

```
d = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['ItemAge'] = ((d-d.groupby(df['Item']).transform('first')).dt.days/7).round().astype(int)
```

output:

```
   Item        Date  ItemAge
0     1  2018-10-01        0
1     2  2018-04-03        0
2     1  2018-10-16        2
3     2  2018-04-15        2
4     1  2018-10-20        3
5     2  2018-04-30        4
```

Comment: Thank you! How does this work ith the 'first' variable? Do I need to create this for each item seperately? Or how can I code this?

Comment: @Karel_Hagen "first" is one of the internal pandas functions

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I will try it out